# Array and Pointers - runtime error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I wrote a program for my assignment that involves pointers and dynamic allocation for an array, I am getting a runtime error and the program crashes, there are no compiling errors. Here is the program :

**array.h :**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void readArray(float*, int &);
void PrintArray(float*, int);
```

**array.cpp :**

```
#include "array.h"

void readArray(float* array, int &size)
{
    array = new float[size];
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the array elements, use spaces: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void PrintArray(float * array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp :**

```
#include "array.h"
int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    cout << "How many elements would you like to enter? ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << endl;
    float *array = NULL;
    readArray(array,size);
    cout << "The array size is " << size << endl;
    PrintArray(array, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output :

```
How many elements would you like to enter? 3
Enter the array elements, use spaces: 4.0 5.0 6.0
The array size is 3
```

*Crashes here*

Can someone let me know what the problem is with the PrintArray function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `array` of `readArray()` is passed by value, so `array` in `main()` remains `NULL` even if you changed it in `readArray()`. To make it be passed by reference. In addition, `size` doesn't need be passed by reference.

change

```
void readArray(float* array, int &size)
```

to

```
void readArray(float*& array, int size)
```

Answer (score 2):

Q: Can someone let me know what the problem is with the PrintArray function?

A: Your PrintArray function is fine.

The problem is that you never pass the array you've allocated outside of readArray.

BETTER:

```
float * 
readArray(int size)
{
    float* array = new float[size];
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the array elements, use spaces: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return array;
}


int main()
   ...
   float *array = readArray(size);
   ...
```

NOTES:

- If you declared a prototype for readArray() in array.h, you'll need to update it.
- There are many ways to accomplish this, but the basic problem is you need `**` (a pointer to a pointer) instead of `*` if you allocate your array inside the function.  I believe passing the array pointer back as a function return is arguably the cleanest solution.

IMHO...